# different view form for edit and create in odoo

Tags: odoo, openerp-8

I'd like to know is it possible to have different form views for edit mode and create mode in odoo ?

Actually I just want to hide some elements in create mode and show it in edit mode.

I've tried to using attrs like :

```
<button name="%(print_invoice)d" string="Cetak Struk" type="action" attrs="{'invisible':[('id', '!=', False)]}" />
```

But when i open the form it gives me error like this :

```
Uncaught Error: Unknown field id in domain [["id","!=",false]]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@qatz

You cannot have different views based on "Edit" or "Create" of record.

You can try this by adding "state" field and based on the value of state you can hide show the elements.

Hope this helps !!

Comment: Thank you for your answer Hardik! You're right I could use the "state" field and give it a default value that changes when user save the form. So when the value changes it'll make the element shown. But it this case is it another simpler way ? so I shouldn't add any script/method in the model. I'll wait for another answer for a moment. Thanks... :D

Answer (score 6):

I have used `attrs="{'invisible': [('id', '=', False)]}"` to hide a field on creation. You must have id as a (hidden) field in your view, like `<field name="id" invisible="1" />`

Comment: this is correct! I wanted to make a field readonly and just setting domain for readonly didn't work for me

Answer (score 5):

you can easily work around this by using "create_date" as a trafic light.

1st expose the field

```
# make creation date visible
create_date = fields.Date(
    'Data',
    invisible=False,
    readonly=True,
)
```

then add it to the form and use it into `attrs` property

```
<field name="create_date" invisible="1" />
<ELEM attrs="{'invisible': [('create_date', '!=', False)]}">
[...]
</ELEM>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @simahawk, it'll help lot of people. The idea is kinda similar with mine but the id field is replaced with create_date. But since my question is asking whether we can have different views for edit and create or not, so to keep the consistency I still choose hardik's answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can have different views for read, edit and create like this if desired

```
<div class="oe_read_only">
   READ ONLY
</div>
<div class="oe_edit_only" attrs="{'invisible':[('id', '=', False)]}">
   EDIT ONLY
</div>
<div attrs="{'invisible':[('id', '!=', False)]}">
   CREATE ONLY
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Since the form wrapped in html tag, I guess it only will work in OpenERP 7.0 and above right?

Comment: @qatz Not sure, I can only say this works for Odoo 10 + which I'm using